# Is there another IE streaming service similar to Spoon?

Tags: internet-explorer

I use [Spoon Browser sandboxes](http://spoon.net/Browsers/) for versions of IE on my computer. It's a great service but recently Microsoft asked them to remove their IE versions from the site.

Does anyone know if there is a similar place I can stream versions of IE?

I installed the IE9 beta on my machine and it messed the entire installation of any IE browser up, happy as I am with not being able to use IE, I still need it to debug my websites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a fully functional browser your best option is to use **Virtual Machines** (I use VirtualBox). **Microsoft itself offers VPC Images** of their browsers at http://microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en

Or you could download **stand-alone versions of IE** from http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm

Also check out the **IE Tester** tool: http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

If you just want to see a **screenshot** (to quickly check layout issues etc.) you could use http://browsershots.org or http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/

Just the other day http://browserling.com just came out and, although time-limited, seems to do what you want ('test real browsers, in a browser'). I have not used it myself though YMMV.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the links! I know about browsershots and tons of other screenshot service but they're just not good enough. As I mentioned before, I cannot use an MS VPC even thoughI used to! I'll check out the stand alone versions, I already have IE-tester but it's really buggy. Thanks :) +1

Comment: Kyle, the finalbuilds stand-alone versions should offer what you need then, various IE installations side-by-side.

Browserling is basically a time-crippled service just like spoon's except that I found the small windows and lack of toolbars/dev-tools a bit of a hassle.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, the IE images are back online. :)

http://www.iecss.com/spoon/

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I recommend virtual machines. You can download **free** virtual machines from Microsoft with all IE versions:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en

Comment: This only applies to users with "Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise, or Ultimate to run Windows XP Mode." I did use this before they changed the rules, so now I need to sandbox browsers.

Answer (score 0):

With the VPCs Frank mentioned, I think you can also use http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/support/virtual-pc-2007.aspx their virtual pc 2007.